# method is not entering using udpatePanel in AsyncPostBack trigger

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I already made this work, but I took back this project and I can hardly understand why now the asp updatepanel is not entering doing the partial update. I want that depending of the selection made at dropdownlist: "incType", the next dropdownlist: "incidentName" shows with some listitems obtained from an sql query. It works by doing an awful postback, but I want it to work on a AsyncPostBack way, few words not refreshing the page, only that part of it.

Front End

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelIncidentNam" runat="server"
    UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <!-- Select input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Category Incident</label>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 selectContainer">
                <div class="input-group inputGroupContainer">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon 
                        glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                    <asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control selectPicker" 
                        name="incType" ID="incType" runat="server" 
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="incType_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                        AutoPostBack="true">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Select input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Incident Name</label>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 selectContainer">
                <div class="input-group inputGroupContainer">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon 
                        glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                    <asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control selectPicker" 
                        name="incidentName" ID="incidentName" 
                        runat="server" AutoPostBack="false">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="incType" 
            EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void incType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    incidentName.Items.Clear();
    incType.Items[0].Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");

    string ConnectionString3 = 
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["incidentDB"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection pmConn3 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString3);
    pmConn3.Open();

    string typeSelected = incType.SelectedValue;

    try
    {
        //querying after index changed from category incident changes
        //querying for site and building data
        string sqlStatement = "SELECT type FROM [dbo].[udt_I&AInvestigation_IncidentType] WHERE category=@category";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, pmConn3);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", typeSelected);

        SqlDataReader reader;
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("type", typeof(string));
        dt.Load(reader);

        reader.Close();

        incidentName.Items.Add(new ListItem("Please select incident name", " "));
        //incidentName.Items[0].Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            incidentName.Items.Add(new ListItem(row[0].ToString(), row[0].ToString()));
        }

        incidentName.Items[0].Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
        incidentName.Items[0].Selected = true;

        pmConn3.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var message = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ex.Message.ToString());
        //Response.Write(message);
        var script = string.Format("alert({0});", message);
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "", script, true);
    }
    finally
    {
        pmConn3.Close();
    }
}
```

I copied just in case the method which it triggers when picking an listitem from the first dropdownlist . Any will help is mostly appreciated as I do not understand what it is missing

Comment: Try removing the triggers. I think they're only needed for controls that are *outside* of the update panel.

Comment: I tried removing all triggers still no effect. If I put it as postbacktrigger it works but obviously doing a refresh through the whole page:
<Triggers>
                       <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="incType" />
                   </Triggers>
any other idea ?